# PHP Composer - set vendor directory

Tags: php, composer-php, yii2, bower

I'm having trouble configuring the vendor path for a Yii2 application. I am adding a couple of lines to the composer.json file I get from the Yii2 basic app template. All I want to do is change the location of my vendor assets.

Below are the changes I have made to the files but I get this error:

```
The file or directory to be published does not exist: /path/to/app/vendor/bower/jquery/dist
```

**But** I'm expecting that particular asset to be published to:

```
/path/to/vendors/bower/jquery/dist
```

No matter what I do, I still get that error message. I suspect it's a Yii2 issue and not a composer issue but I'm not sure. Anyone got any ideas? Thanks in advance.

### Files...

#### index.php

```
// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require('/path/to/vendors/autoload.php');
require('/path/to/vendors/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

#### composer.json

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
    "description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        ...
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "vendor-dir": "/path/to/vendors"
    },
    "require": {
        "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "~1.0",
        ...
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "../../includes/vendors/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "../../includes/vendors/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out there's a there's a simple solution: If you want to change the location of your vendor assets then you must follow these simple steps:

1. include the composer-asset-plugin in your `composer.json` file

   ```
   "require": {
       "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "*"
   }
   ```
2. include the composer-asset-plugin directive in your extra config. in your composer.json file:

   ```
   "extra": {
   "asset-installer-paths": {
           "npm-asset-library": "../../path/to/vendors/npm",
           "bower-asset-library": "../../path/to/vendors/bower"
       }
   }
   ```
3. add the vendor location to the config section in your composer.json file:

   ```
   "config": {
       "vendor-dir": "../../path/to/vendors"
   }
   ```
4. update web/index.php to point to the new vendor location:

   ```
   require(__DIR__ . '/../../../path/to/vendors/autoload.php');
   require(__DIR__ . '/../../../path/to/vendors/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
   ```
5. include a vendorPath definition in your config/web.php:

   ```
   'vendorPath' => '../../../path/to/vendors',
   ```

That should work with the vanilla Yii2 basic template.

Comment: This is not working.. and the path you have mentioned is not matured.

Comment: I had the asset-plugin, but bringing it up to the latest version fixed my issues.

Comment: With composer v1.10.8 I just needed to follow the step n.3

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
sudo cp -R bower-asset/* bower
```

Simply copy all files and folders from bower-asset to bower.

Answer (score 1):

The [`asset-installer-paths` directive](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#define-a-custom-directory-for-the-assets-installation) belongs to the Composer plugin `fxp/composer-asset-plugin`.
The plugin is required, for this directive to work. But it seems that you are not requiring it in your project repo or globally.

Try a global installation:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0"
```

[Docu - Installation](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#installation)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation but I already have `"fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "~1.0"` in my require; and I have tried  `"fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "*"` - neither worked; I get the same error.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried the default install for yii2-app-basic with default folders? And in your require section you have `"bower-asset/jquery": "2.1.3"` defined, to include jQ?

Comment: Yep. I have installed it using the instructions as per the Yii2 Definitive Guide, and this works as expected. I have just tried it explicitly adding `"bower-asset/jquery": "2.1.3"` but this is implicitly included in my dependencies: this didn't appear to change anything. Running `composer update` and browsing to the site gives me the same error. The problem is, I think, that Yii2 is looking in the wrong directory for the asset. Composer hasn't passed it on to Yii2.

Comment: Yes, i think that, too. Yii2 would have to read the custom path and use it as the basePath for assets in the AssetManager. This should work automatically, if not, then it's an issue or feature request. Maybe it's possible to set the path manually in the config: `'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
       'jquery.min.js' => '/path/to/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    ],
]`. That should work, but is tedious...

Comment: Yeah I could do that, and it would work, but I'd have to manually modify each plugin that I would use. I have figured out the problem and have answered it below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes, because the old assets plugin installed files in `vendor/bower` and `vendor/npm`, but since composer no longer needs this plugin and installs below `vendor/bower-assets` and `vendor/npm-assets`.

You only need the following lines in your config

```php
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
```

That changes the place where youre assets are looking for the @bower and @npm directories.
After this change you can completely remove the `composer-asset-plugin` from your require block and the `asset-installer-paths` from your extras block.

**Bonus:** If you like to move the whole vendor-directory you can add

```php
'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/includes/vendor'`
```

to modify the vendor-path to whever place you like.
Keep in mind to move your composer.json to this directory too, or consider changing [vendor-dir](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir) in your composer config